# Why do I have an IOException in this case?

Tags: c#, logging, nlog, ioexception

I'm programming a video player in C# (the video works fine) and what I need now is to get the libvlc logs as well as my custom logs to print them in a file.

I use NLog which handles the libvlc logs (with nVLC) and I raise an event for my custom logs, and in buth cases this function is called :

```
private static void tracerlogs(string erreur, VLCControl.ControleUtilisateurVLC.LogLevels LvLog)
{
   string path = "logs.txt";//Sera redéfini dans l'appli
   if (!File.Exists(path))
   {
       // Create a file to write to.
       using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path))
       {
           sw.WriteLine(erreur + " " + LvLog.ToString());
           sw.Close();
       }
   }
   else
   {
       using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(path))
       {
           sw.WriteLine(erreur + " " + LvLog.ToString());
           sw.Close();
       }
   }
   Console.WriteLine(erreur + " " + LvLog.ToString());
}
```

The problem is that I'm getting at random times a System.IO.IOException telling that "the process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process". Although I do close my StreamWriter (which should normally not be useful in a `using` block)... This makes my app crash. Does anyone have any idea why it does this ?

Comment: Is the file already in the folder when you start your app or do you insert them in the folder when the app is running ?

Comment: How many threads access this method? Why do you want to reinvent the wheel and don't you use something like log4net?

Comment: Is "tracerlogs" maybe called from more than one thread ?

Comment: Since you are using events, you might want to have a look a your threading

Comment: If the file is in the folder, I open it and att text to it, if not, I create it, so it should work no matter if the file is in the directory or not. But, in those last cases, This file is already in the folder. What I don't get, is that everything works fine and the app crashes at a random time.

Comment: @CodeCaster I need to raise events from an user control to let the WinForm handle them. I was wondering this could be something with my threads, do I need a delegate then ?

Comment: definitely a threading problem (more than one thread calling the tracerlogs method). Log4Net is really good

Comment: Ok, it's solved. As I could not used `BeginInvoke` in a static context, I used a `lock` :
I declare a `public static readonly object Locklog = new Object();` at the beginning, and I wrap the code of my function like this :
`public [...] tracerlogs(myargs){ lock(Locklog){ /* bunch of code */ } }`

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it by adding a resource : as there was a conflict between different threads trying to access this function, I wrapped this :

```
    private static void tracerlogs(string erreur, VLCControl.ControleUtilisateurVLC.LogLevels LvLog)
    {
        lock (LockLog) {
        string path = "logs.txt";//Sera redéfini dans l'appli
        if (!File.Exists(path))
        {
            // Create a file to write to.
            using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path))
            {
                sw.WriteLine(erreur + " " + LvLog.ToString());
                sw.Close();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(path))
            {
                sw.WriteLine(erreur + " " + LvLog.ToString());
                sw.Close();
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine(erreur + " " + LvLog.ToString());
        }
    }
```

And I declare a `public static readonly object LockLog = new Object();` in my class. This works just fine ! Thanks to those who told me that this had to see with threading.